# Which Ending of Undertale I got? and What remaining endings I have now?

Tags: undertale

I have just completed Undertale, but I am not sure which ending I got. As per [wiki](https://undertale.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Endings), I must have gotten The True Pacifist Route Ending.
But I did not get any epilogue as shown in [The Wiki](https://undertale.fandom.com/wiki/True_Pacifist_Route) page.

> I killed Toriel(didn't know consequences), I am friends with Sans, Papyrus, and Undyn. I spared Asgore, but then Flowey killed him, I defeated Flowey and spared him too. In the end, Flowey just popped out of nowhere and told me to try to replay the game without killing anyone then he might spare The King.

Now I am really confused, Where is the epilogue I am looking for, which ending did I get, as it might affect my next run.
I want to play and end this game in as many possible ways as I can.
Also, I have the game off steam and I have read that reset or deleting saves won't help me as the steam cloud will resync them again.

Which Ending is this and which next endings I can achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say *I killed Toriel*, you certainly got the Neutral Route Ending, as Toriel is one of the monsters you must spare in order to obtain the True Pacifist Route Ending.

In order to obtain the True Pacifist Route Ending, you will need to restart your game from the beginning and kill no monsters at all while also befriending Papyrus and Undyne (so, go on Papyrus's date with him, pour a cup of water on Undyne when given the chance, and later go to Undyne's house when invited to do so by Papyrus). If you do all this correctly, after defeating Asgore and Flowey a second time, you will instead get a different conversation with Flowey that will direct you to a newly-unlocked sidequest and bonus dungeon that will lead you to obtaining True Pacifist.

Additionally, resetting or deleting saves is fine in your situation; the cloud save resync effect in Undertale only changes your options if you have obtained the Genocide Route Ending by murdering every single possible monster, which you have not done.